# Ошибка 550 при копировании с FTP сервера (Win2k8 R2)

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

Помогите с настройкой FTP-сервера под Win2k8 R2!

1. На Win2k8 R2 настроен FTP сервер.
2. По UNC пути открываю в Excel файл, находящийся на "FTP ресурсе"
3. При копировании с FTP-сервера FTP-клиентом файла указанного в п.2 пулучаю ошибку: "550 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process", т.е. не дает копировать открытые файлы.

P.s.: При использовании FTP сервера на Win2k таких проблем нет.

Comment: В Inete 3 дня безрезультатно искал ответа на свой вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Все правильно попробуйте закрыть файл.

The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process - Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, потому что он занят другим процессом.

Comment: Вопрос состоит именно в том как сделать, чтобы можно было копировать с сервера открытые файлы!

Comment: FTP от мелкософта ? тогда в настройках в mms там же где всякие iis только ftp в Advanced Settings найти Allow Reading Files While Uploading

Comment: Этот параметр уже пробовал - не помогает. Да он и не может почочь ведь речь идет об "Uploading"